# Change shape of an object of dataset based on array of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Suppose I have:

```js
const KEYS = ['b', 'a', 'c']
const obj = {
  2018: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
  2019: {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6},
  2020: {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9},
}
```

This is what I would like to get:

```js
const result = {
 2018: { 
    a: [0, 1, 0], 
    b: [2, 0, 0], 
    c: [0, 0, 3] 
  },
 2019: { 
    a: [0, 4, 0], 
    b: [5, 0, 0], 
    c: [0, 0, 6] 
  },,
 2020: { 
    a: [0, 7, 0], 
    b: [8, 0, 0], 
    c: [0, 0, 9] 
  },
}
```

result['2018'] object has three keys. Each key value is an array that contains the values in the order that is set by KEYS using 0 as fill value.

How can I do something like this?
This is what I tried but obviously is more complicated than this:

```js
const reshaped = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
  return { [key]: Object.values(value) }
})

// [
//  { 2018: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
//  { 2019: [ 4, 5, 6 ] },
//  { 2020: [ 7, 8, 9 ] }
// ]
```

Comment: @Dai edit the main message, sorry

Comment: You wrote _"Each key value is an array that contains the values in the order that is set by KEYS using 0 as fill value."_ - I don't understand what you mean.  Please post a thorough explanation of how your desired output is generated (using plain English is fine) - from what you've posted I don't understand how `KEYS` is meant to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the wanted keys in order abd build an array for each property.

```js
const
    KEYS = ['b', 'a', 'c'],
    object = { 2018: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, 2019: { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 }, 2020: { a: 7, b: 8, c: 9 } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).map(([k, o]) => [
        k,
        Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([l, v]) => [
            l,
            KEYS.map(m => l === m ? v : 0)
        ]))
    ]));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` to map the object and then just create a new array with the length of the KEYS arr.

```js
const KEYS = ['b', 'a', 'c']
const obj = {
  2018: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
  2019: {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6},
  2020: {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9},
}

const result = Object.fromEntries( // Create obj from array of entries
  Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => [ // create array of entries from obj and map it
    key,
    Object.fromEntries( // do the same obj/arr transformation on the value
      Object.entries(value).map(([subKey, subValue]) => {
        const arr = new Array(KEYS.length).fill(0); // create new array of keys length and fill all zeroes
        arr[KEYS.indexOf(subKey)] = subValue; // on the index of the key in the KEYS arr, set the value of the key

        return [subKey, arr]; // return subValue
      })
    )
  ])
);

console.log(result);
```